# All palindrome numbers from 1 to 100,000 in C++

Tags: c++, palindrome

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with this little piece of code, its supposed to print all palindrome numbers from 1 to 100,000 (I know its a lot of numbers). I'm new here and I think this might be a simple fix but I cant figure it out, thanks.

When I run the program, it just gives: "100000 is not a palindrome......................................................................................................"

(its supposed to print numbers like: 111, 121, 131, 141.....till 100000)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  int n=0, reverse = 0, temp=0, i=0;
  n=100000;
  for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
       temp = i;
       while( temp != 0 )
         {
           reverse = reverse * 10;
           reverse = reverse + temp % 10;
           temp = temp/10;
         }

       if( i == reverse )
         printf("%d", n);
       else
         printf(".");
    }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be a good time to try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what's really going on (hint: there's at least one fairly obvious bug in the code - if you can't see it already then it should become readily apparent when you step into the while loop).

Comment: <facepalm> Start the debugger, place some breakpoints, study!

Comment: You might have to use a string to convert the number correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166886/reverse-of-a-number

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 obvious defects in your code:

1. You don't clear `reverse` before each iteration so values from previous iterations are accumulating and breaking algorithm.
2. In `printf` you shall output the current checked number, not `n`.

Another modern C++ fashionable style hints:

1. Declare variables as locally as possible. You can declare them inside the loop, seriously! E.g. `temp` and `reverse` shall be declared right before `while`, `i` shall be declared inside `for()` statement.
2. Use `*=`, `-=`, `+=` instead of `=`:

   ```
   reverse *= 10;
   reverse += temp % 10;
   temp /= 10;
   ```
3. Use `std::cout` instead of "old good C" `printf()`

Comment: Great examples for why you should 1) declare variables in the smallest possible scope, and 2) give descriptive names to variables, like `maxNumber` instead of `n`.

Comment: May be it is just plain `C`? Variable declarations, types used, functions, includes - everything is `C` like.

Comment: @Lol4t0 OP tagged it C++. And most of hints except `std::cout` are valid for modern `C`

Answer (score 0):

In debug, reverse the number a second time and assert that reversing twice brings you back to the same number.

```
int reverse = doReverse( temp );
assert( temp == doReverse( reverse ));
```

You will find your error.

Comment: There's some good advice in this answer. Separate the reversing functionality into its own function, and perform tests to ensure it is working. One caveat though: if you double-reverse a number that ends in zero, it won't return the original number. So the testing method should skip over those.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    string lStr;

    for (int lIter = 1; lIter <= 100000; ++lIter ) {
    stringstream lStrS;
    lStrS << lIter;
    lStr = lStrS.str();

    string lRevStr = lStr;
    reverse( lRevStr.begin(), lRevStr.end() );

    if ( lRevStr == lStr ) {
        cout << lStr << endl;
    }
 }
```

}

This is an example of one way to do it.