# The most efficient way to reverse a number

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, optimization

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to reverse a number, e.g.

**Input:** 3456789

**Output:** 9876543

In C++ there are plenty of options with shifting and bit masks but what would be the most efficient way ?

My platform: x86_64

Numbers range: XXX - XXXXXXXXXX (3 - 9 digits)

**EDIT**
Last digit of my input will never be a zero so there is no leading zeros problem.

Comment: If you're not treating it as a number, why not just read it as a string? Reversing it is then trivial.

Comment: @hvd This would cause calls to string constructor, assignment operator, destructor ... I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way.

Comment: Do you want leading zeroes? Both the answers provided fail for cases with leading zeroes.

Comment: You can store it in a `char[10]` if you're worried about the efficiency of `std::string` (though I wouldn't be).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166886/reverse-of-a-number)

Comment: Do you really need "the most efficient way"? Is this really where all the processing time will be spent in your program? Sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: Not a duplicate; linked Q was specifically about leading zeroes.

Comment: Shifting and bitmasks? Not in base 10. If you wanted to do this in base 16 I would have some nice tricks up my sleeve, but binary computers just don't like base 10.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long in = 3456789;
    long out = 0;
    while(in)
    {
        out *= 10;
        out += in % 10;
        in /= 10;
    }
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 This answer is really extremely common. Not very hard or impressive enough to be copied.

Comment: @H2CO3 no, I wrote separately, actually

Comment: @H2CO3 - Hm, I was replying to your answer but you seem to have deleted your answer. I only temporarily removed my upvote because I realized I should research math.stackexchange.com in case a more efficient solution (_e.g._ a one-step formula) existed. However the mathematicians there have not come up with any such thing, only [a compact form](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323268/formula-to-reverse-digits) of the algorithm you (and Stephen Lin) have written. So, upvote restored, in spirit.

Comment: @acheong87 Thanks. I removed my answer since it turned out to be wrong, just like this one is. It doesn't count trailing zeroes, `XYZ0` becomes `ZYX` instead of `0ZYX`.

Comment: @H2CO3 i don't mind taking this down too but it's not clear what OP wants since he mentions bit shifting and such (so presumably he wants a numerical rather than string representation)

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int reverse(unsigned int val)
{
 unsigned int retval = 0;

 while( val > 0)
 {
     retval  = 10*retval + val%10;
     val     /= 10;
 }
 printf("returning - %d", retval);
 return retval;
}


int main()
{
    reverse(123);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may convert the number to string and then reverse the string with STL algorithms. Code below should work:

```
 long number = 123456789;
 stringstream ss;
 ss << number;
 string numberToStr = ss.str();

 std::reverse(numberToStr.begin(), numberToStr.end());

 cout << atol(numberToStr.c_str());
```

You may need to include those relevant header files. I am not sure whether it is the most efficient way, but STL algorithms are generally very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
static public int getReverseInt(int value) {
    int resultNumber = 0;
    for (int i = value; i != 0;) {
        int d = i / 10;
        resultNumber = (resultNumber - d) * 10 + i;
        i = d;
    }
    return resultNumber;
}
```

I think this will be the fastest possible method without using `asm`. Note that `d*10 + i` is equivalent to `i%10` but much faster since modulo is around 10 times slower than multiplication.
  I tested it and it is about 25 % faster than other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
int ans=0;
int rev(int n)
{
  ans=(ans+(n%10))*10; // using recursive function to reverse a number;
  if(n>9) 
    rev(n/10);
}

int main()
{
  int m=rev(456123); // m=32
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Not in view of memory but comes handy when solving problems :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Recursive method to find the reverse of a number  
 #include <bits/stdc++.h> 
    using namespace std; 
    int reversDigits(int num) 
    { 
    static int rev_num = 0; 
    static int base_pos = 1; 
    if(num > 0) 
    { 
        reversDigits(num/10); 
        rev_num += (num%10)*base_pos; 
        base_pos *= 10; 
    } 
    return rev_num; 
    } 
    int main() 
    { 
        int num = 4562; 
        cout << "Reverse  " << reversDigits(num); 
    } ``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// recursive method to reverse number. lang = java
static void reverseNumber(int number){
    // number == 0 is the base case
    if(number !=0 ){
        //recursive case
        System.out.print(number %10);
        reverseNumber(number /10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not as efficient but it does solve the problem and can be useful.
It returns long long for any signed integer(int, long, long long, etc) and unsigned long long for any unsigned integer (unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long long, etc).

The char type depends of compiler implementation can be signed or unsigned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


template <bool B>
struct SignedNumber
{
};

template <>
struct SignedNumber<true>
{
    typedef long long type;
};

template <>
struct SignedNumber<false>
{
    typedef unsigned long long type;
};

template <typename TNumber = int,
          typename TResult = typename SignedNumber<std::is_signed<TNumber>::value>::type,
          typename = typename std::void_t<std::enable_if_t<std::numeric_limits<TNumber>::is_integer>>>
TResult ReverseNumber(TNumber value)
{
    bool isSigned = std::is_signed_v<TNumber>;
    int sign = 1;
    if (value < 0)
    {
        value *= -1;
        sign = -1;
    }
    std::string str = std::to_string(value);
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    return isSigned ? std::stoll(str) * sign : std::stoull(str) * sign;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(true) << std::endl; //bool -> unsigned long long
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(false) << std::endl; //bool -> unsigned long long
    std::cout << ReverseNumber('@') << std::endl; //char -> long long or unsigned long long 
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(46) << std::endl; //int -> long long
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(-46) << std::endl; //int -> long long
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(46U) << std::endl; //unsigned int -> unsigned long long
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(46L) << std::endl; //long -> long long
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(-46LL) << std::endl; //long long -> long long
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(46UL) << std::endl; //unsigned long -> unsigned long long
    std::cout << ReverseNumber(4600ULL) << std::endl; //unsigned long long -> unsigned long long
}
```

**Output**

```
1
0
64
64
-64
64
64
-64
64
64
```

**Test this code**
https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/IntegerToStr#main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

If it is 32-bit unsigned integer (987,654,321 being max input) and if you have 4GB free memory(by efficiency, did you mean memory too?),

```
result=table[value]; // index 12345 has 54321, index 123 has 321
```

should be fast enough. Assuming memory is accessed at 100 ns time or 200 cycles and integer is 7 digits on average, other solutions have these:

- 7 multiplications,
- 7 adds,
- 7 modulo,
- 7 divisions,
- 7 loop iterations with 7 comparisons

if these make more than 100 nanoseconds / 200 cycles, then table would be faster. For example, 1 integer division can be as high as 40 cycles, so I guess this can be fast enough. If inputs are repeated, then data will coming from cache will have even less latency.

But if there are millions of reversing operations in parallel, then computing by CPU is absolutely the better choice (probably 30x-100x speedup using vectorized compute loop + multithreading) than accessing table. It has multiple pipelines per core and multiple cores. You can even choose CUDA/OpenCL with a GPU for extra throughput and this reversing solution from other answers look like perfectly embarrassingly parallelizable since 1 input computes independently of other inputs.

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest one:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int number, reversed=0;
cout<<"Input a number to Reverse: ";
cin>>number;
    while(number!=0)
  {
    reversed= reversed*10;
    reversed=reversed+number%10;
    number=number/10;
  }
cout<<"Reversed number is: "<<reversed<<endl;

}
```