# Compiler not calculating correctly?

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to make a simple program that prints a number on reverse, I have these 2 functions:

```
void get_numbas(int numbah){

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        step1 = numbah % (int)pow(10,i);
        step2 = step1/(int)pow(10,i-1);
        std::cout << step2;
    }
}
```

My input for second function is `12345`, on the second iteration, `step1` should become `45`, i have tested on main

```
int test = 12345; 
int step1 = test % (int)pow(10,2); //45
```

But when I debug, at second iteration I see that `step1` becomes `69` (I have no idea why). So my input is `12345`, and it should reverse it to `54321`, but thanks to this awkward bad calculation at the second iteration it's printing `56321` (because it uses 69/10 instead of 45/10). Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

[SCREENSHOT OF MY OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGJAM.png)

Answer (score 1):

`pow` is a floating point function.  There are inherent inaccuracies in floating point. The result of `pow(10,5)` might turn out to be `9999.999999837204183` or something like that.  Then your code rounds DOWN (instead of rounding to nearest integer), producing an unintended result.

This explains your observation of `69` on the second iteration, because `12345 % 99` gives `69`.

I would suggest redesigning your code, which is integer-based, to not use intermediate floating point operations, e.g. :

```
 uint32_t dividend = 1;

 for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
 {
    step1 = numbah % (dividend * 10);
    step2 = step1 / dividend;
    dividend *= 10;
    std::cout << step2;
}
```

Comment: However there are many questions [containing code for number reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355080/the-most-efficient-way-to-reverse-a-number) already.

Comment: Hey this actually fixed my code on the text editor, thanks for the explanation. Interesting to see how my text editor interprets decimals differently from IDES.